# $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} f(x)=0$ meaning

Tags: limits, notation

I was wondering if this limit $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} f(x)=0$ is correct to be interpreted as:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)=0?$$

Is this correct?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, it's better to interpret it that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $M$ such that if $|x|\geq M$ then $|f(x)|<\varepsilon$. This way we have a ready generalization if $f$ is from one normed vector space to another.

Comment: While $\lim_{|x| \rightarrow \infty}$ can be interpreted as you described, it is also often used if $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector. Then, it referes to every combination of entries that make the vector norm of $x$ infinite.

Answer (score 0):

For $x \in \mathbb{R}$, yes. In general, it would be interpreted as "for every sequence $(x_n) \in \mathbb{K}^n$, $|x_n| \rightarrow \infty$ implies $f(x_n) \rightarrow 0$.